# Can't get the SUM function to work with my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I'm trying to SUM some warehouse stock values, grouped by zones, but can't get it to work.

The following query returns all materials on stock. Same material is placed on more locations, in more zones. So material AAA can be located on two locations in zone 111, and three locations in zone 222

```
SELECT  Zones.Label,
    Materials.Material,
    Shelves.Label as ShelfLabel,
    Items.StockQty

    FROM Zones INNER JOIN
        (dbo.LangTexts(null) AS Texts INNER JOIN (WarehouseStatus INNER JOIN
              (Shelves INNER JOIN (Positions INNER JOIN
                    (Materials INNER JOIN Items
                    ON Materials.Material = Items.Material)
                    ON Positions.ID = Items.Owner)
                    ON Shelves.ID = Positions.Owner)
                    ON WarehouseStatus.Status = Items.Status)
                    ON Texts.TextID = WarehouseStatus.Text)
                    ON Zones.ID = Shelves.Owner
    WHERE Zones.Label IS NOT NULL   
    ORDER BY Materials.Material, Zones.Label
```

Output:

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs2wo.png)

As I have tried to markup in the screenshot, I need the total StockQty grouped by zone (label column)

I'm trying to achieve that by modifying the query like this.

```
SELECT  Zones.Label,
    Materials.Material,
    Shelves.Label as ShelfLabel,
    SUM(Items.StockQty)

    FROM Zones INNER JOIN
        (dbo.LangTexts(null) AS Texts INNER JOIN (WarehouseStatus INNER JOIN
              (Shelves INNER JOIN (Positions INNER JOIN
                    (Materials INNER JOIN Items
                    ON Materials.Material = Items.Material)
                    ON Positions.ID = Items.Owner)
                    ON Shelves.ID = Positions.Owner)
                    ON WarehouseStatus.Status = Items.Status)
                    ON Texts.TextID = WarehouseStatus.Text)
                    ON Zones.ID = Shelves.Owner
    WHERE Zones.Label IS NOT NULL   
    GROUP BY Zones.Label
    ORDER BY Materials.Material, Zones.Label
```

But it keeps returning the following error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Column 'Materials.Material' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have been dealing with such error before, but don't understand exactly what I'm doing wrong. Sometimes I succeed by changing the query back and forth, but this time I really stuck.

Hope that someone is possible to guide me.

Thank's in advance.

---

As the column Shelves.Label actually not bring any value in this matter, I ended up with the following query based on @Md.SumanKabir's answer.

```
SELECT  Zones.Label,
    Materials.Material,
    SUM(Items.StockQty)

    FROM Zones INNER JOIN
        (dbo.LangTexts(null) AS Texts INNER JOIN (WarehouseStatus INNER JOIN
              (Shelves INNER JOIN (Positions INNER JOIN
                    (Materials INNER JOIN Items
                    ON Materials.Material = Items.Material)
                    ON Positions.ID = Items.Owner)
                    ON Shelves.ID = Positions.Owner)
                    ON WarehouseStatus.Status = Items.Status)
                    ON Texts.TextID = WarehouseStatus.Text)
                    ON Zones.ID = Shelves.Owner
    WHERE Zones.Label IS NOT NULL   
    GROUP BY Zones.Label, Materials.Material
    ORDER BY Materials.Material, Zones.Label
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: That join style is horrible, if they are all `inner` joins then you may as well do `inner join table1 on ... inner join table2 on ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query would be :

```
SELECT  Zones.Label,
Materials.Material,
Shelves.Label as ShelfLabel,
SUM(Items.StockQty)
FROM Zones INNER JOIN
    (dbo.LangTexts(null) AS Texts INNER JOIN (WarehouseStatus INNER JOIN
          (Shelves INNER JOIN (Positions INNER JOIN
                (Materials INNER JOIN Items
                ON Materials.Material = Items.Material)
                ON Positions.ID = Items.Owner)
                ON Shelves.ID = Positions.Owner)
                ON WarehouseStatus.Status = Items.Status)
                ON Texts.TextID = WarehouseStatus.Text)
                ON Zones.ID = Shelves.Owner
WHERE Zones.Label IS NOT NULL   
GROUP BY Zones.Label, Materials.Material, Shelves.Label
ORDER BY Materials.Material, Zones.Label
```

You need to use the columns in **GROUP BY** which are not used in any aggregate functions like **SUM**

You can get more information on how to use **GROUP BY** [Here](https://learnsql.com/blog/examples-of-sql-group-by/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your grouping does not match your select. You select 3 columns `Zones.Label`, `Materials.Material` and `Shelves.Label`, but you group only by `Zones.Label`. Therefore, it does not know what to do with the 2 other columns.

Either you have to aggregate them like you did with the sum or you have to add them to the grouping.